# Understanding code of Weka

Tags: java, model, linear-regression, weka

I am studying the [machine learning book, written by Boštjan Kaluža, Pact publishing](https://www.packtpub.com/big-data-and-business-intelligence/machine-learning-java).

Here is the brief definition of the code.

> The code that aims to investigate the heating and cooling load
>   requirements of the buildings based on their construction
>   characteristics such as surface, wall and roof area, height, hazing
>   area, and compactness.The researchers used a simulator to design 12
>   different house configurations while varying 18 building
>   characteristics. Our first goal is to systematically analyze the
>   impact each building characterizes has on the target variable, that
>   is, heating or cooling load. We will use the linear regression
>   model for estimation. Linear regression model constructed a function
>   that linearly combines the input variables to estimate the heating
>   load.

The table below shows the data that we analyze : 
[image]

Here is the code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
  BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

  System.out.print("Enter the path of the data file:");      
  String s = br.readLine();

  // load CSV     
  CSVLoader loader = new CSVLoader();     
  loader.setSource(new File(s));

  Instances data = loader.getDataSet();

  //We will start with learning a model for heating load by setting the class 
  //attribute at the feature position
  data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);

  //The second target variable—cooling load—can be now removed:
  Remove remove = new Remove();
  remove.setOptions(new String[]{"-R", data.numAttributes()+""});
  remove.setInputFormat(data);  
  data = Filter.useFilter(data, remove);

  data.setClassIndex(data.numAttributes() - 1);
  LinearRegression model = new LinearRegression();
  model.buildClassifier(data); 
  System.out.println(model);      
}
```

At the code, we have removed "The second target variable—cooling load". The question that I want to ask is, Why did we do this? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

x1 to xn are input
y1 to y2 are target (output).
They want first to to linear regression for x1 to y1, e.g. heating load. That's why they remove the last one.

Answer (score 1):

Most likely there will be two models; one to predict the heating load and one to predict the cooling load. Reason being is that trying to predict them both together would result in multivariate regression, and not in linear regression. In linear regression there is only one dependent variable.